# Cascading Dropdown using JQuery/Ajax return data repeating first table row

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Jquery/Ajax to return data based on cascading dropdowns. When select1 is chosen it fills select2. The functionality seems to work fine but the data returned for select2 is the value of the first row repeated x number of times for the number of rows returned. Why is this happening?

DBContext:

```
public class FulfillmentContext : DbContext
{
    public FulfillmentContext()
        : base("name=FulfillmentContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Carrier> Carriers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Fulfillment> Fulfillments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CarrierService> CarrierServices { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class FulfillmentController : Controller
{
FulfillmentContext db = new FulfillmentContext();

//GET Fulfillment
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetCarriers()
{
    return Json(db.Carriers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetServicesByCarrierId(string carrierId)
{
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(carrierId);

    try
    {
        var services = db.CarrierServices.Where(s => s.CarrierId == Id).ToList();

        return Json(services);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }                        
}      
}
```

View:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">REPORT OPTIONS</div>
<div class="panel-body" style="padding-left:35px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("Carrier:")
@Html.DropDownList("carriers", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select a Carrier", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: auto; margin: 0 0 25px 0;" })

@Html.Label("Carrier Services:")
@Html.DropDownList("services", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select a Service", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: auto; margin: 0 0 25px 0;" })
</div>
}
</div>
</div>
</div>
@section scripts{
<script src="~/assets/scripts/form-plugin.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/Fulfillment/GetCarriers",
datatype: "Json",
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#carriers').append('<option value="' + value.CarrierId + '">' + value.CarrierName + '</option>');
    });
}
});

$('#carriers').change(function () {

$('#services').empty();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Fulfillment/GetServicesByCarrierId",
    datatype: "Json",
    data: { CarrierId: $('#carriers').val() },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#services').append('<option value="' + value.Code + '">' + value.WebName + '</option>');
        });
    }
});
});

});
}
```

[image]

CONSOLE.LOG(data)

```
(7) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
CarrierId: 1
​​
Code: "1DM"
​​
Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early"
​​
SortOrder: 2
​​
WebName: "UPS Next Air Early"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { CarrierId: 1, Code: "1DM", Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early", … }
​
2: Object { CarrierId: 1, Code: "1DM", Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early", … }
​
3: Object { CarrierId: 1, Code: "1DM", Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early", … }
​
4: Object { CarrierId: 1, Code: "1DM", Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early", … }
​
5: Object { CarrierId: 1, Code: "1DM", Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early", … }
​
6: Object { CarrierId: 1, Code: "1DM", Description: "UPS Next Day Air® Early", … }
​
length: 7
```

Comment: please try console.log(data)  for services and check what is returning

Answer (score 0):

You need clear select tag before append data from Ajax data using  `$('#services').empty()`

```
success: function (data) {
        $('#services').empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#services').append('<option value="' + value.Code + '">' + value.WebName + '</option>');
        });
```

Script change to:

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/Fulfillment/GetCarriers",
datatype: "Json",
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#carriers').empty();
        $('#carriers').append('<option value="' + value.CarrierId + '">' + value.CarrierName + '</option>');
    });
}
});

$('#carriers').change(function () {

$('#services').empty();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Fulfillment/GetServicesByCarrierId",
    datatype: "Json",
    data: { CarrierId: $('#carriers').val() },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#services').empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#services').append('<option value="' + value.Code + '">' + value.WebName + '</option>');
        });
    }
});
});

});
}
```

Comment: I put empty outside each method? Did you try?

Comment: This does not solve my issue. When select1 is changed select2 values repeat themselves. example: If I choose UPS in select1 which is carrierid 1 select2 has 7 options in the database, but select2 fills with Next Day Air,Next Day Air,Next Day Air,Next Day Air,Next Day Air,Next Day Air. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove duplicate item in 7 items from DB?

Comment: No. I have edited my question above with an image of the resulting code. Each value in the services select field should be 7 different values not the same repeated 7 times.

Comment: Yes I did. Everything looks right but the results are not.

Comment: Did you try console.log(data) in success function?

Comment: Yes. Edited above.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this issue? I am beating my head against the wall. Thanks!

Comment: see console log, it is the issue from GetServicesByCarrierId method